# Page explaining how to add social bookmarking buttons for one's web pages

Tags: html

I maintain [a homepage](http://www.shlomifish.org) where I want to place the so-called social bookmarking buttons/icons for people to share the pages on such resources as Digg, Reddit, Delicious, Stumble Upon, etc. I've formerly used the [AddThis button](http://www.addthis.com/), but then it started sucking, so I switched to [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) which was better. However, now ShareThis have added a dependency on Google Analytics for their JavaScript code, which I do not want and which they said that "At this time, there is no way to disable our widget from accessing Google Analytics.".

So right now I'd like to set up my own links of "Share this site" using social bookmarking sites at the raw HTML. I found [this page with links to lots of graphics for this](http://allthatsnew.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/social-bookmarking-buttons-25-sets-of-free-stunning-web-20-icons-over-500-icons/) but it doesn't explain how to add the relevant mark-up.

So I'm asking here. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this, not sure if that helps you, can change the images and replace the feed with your own. Find more "subscribe links" and "bookmark links" like it.

```
<a href="http://add.my.yahoo.com/rss?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://us.i1.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/my/addtomyyahoo4.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.bloglines.com/sub/http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.bloglines.com/images/sub_modern9.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.newsgator.com/ngs/subscriber/subext.aspx?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.newsgator.com/images/ngsub1.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://my.msn.com/addtomymsn.armx?id=rss&amp;ru=http://forum.go-here.nl&amp;ut=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://sc.msn.com/44/G,UCH%7BZBSS3%7BOS%7BSE469LG.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.bitty.com/manual/?contenttype=rssfeed&amp;contentvalue=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.bitty.com/img/bittychicklet_91x17.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://technorati.com/faves?add=http://forum.go-here.nl"><img src="http://static.technorati.com/pix/fave/tech-fav-5.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://feeds.my.aol.com/add.jsp?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://myfeeds.aolcdn.com/vis/myaol_cta1.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://rss2pdf.com?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://rss2pdf.com/images/rss2pdf.png" border="0"></a><a href="http://solosub.com/sub/http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://solosub.com/feed_button.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.eskobo.com/?AddToMyPage=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.eskobo.com/images/eneskobo.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.netvibes.com/subscribe.php?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.netvibes.com/img/add2netvibes.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.pageflakes.com/subscribe.aspx?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.pageflakes.com/subscribe2.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.protopage.com/add-button-site?label=forum.go-here.nl&amp;type=feed&amp;url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.protopage.com/web/images/buttons/add-site-to-protopage.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://reader.earthlink.net/feed/add?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://my.eimg.net/img/logo_myeln.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://plusmo.com/add?url=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://plusmo.com/res/graphics/fbplusmo.gif" border="0"></a><a href="http://www.ifeedreaders.com/subscribe.php?thefeed=http://feeds.feedburner.com/go-here"><img src="http://www.ifeedreaders.com/buttons/button2.gif" title="" border="0"></a><br>
```